# How to display an icon/image on uicollectionviewcell after it has been selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a uiCollectionViewCell which loads image from an api. I want to display another image/icon on the cell when a user clicks on it. In my custom cell I have two images one which display the image from the URL and the second one is the one I would like to show if the user has clicked on it. I'm doing this to alert the user that they have selected that cell. Below is my sample code

```
protocol ModalDelegate {
func changeValue(userChoice: String, rateMovieID: String, rateImageUrl: String, title: String)
}

class GuestRateMovieView: UIViewController, ModalDelegate {
func changeValue(userChoice: String, rateMovieID: String, rateImageUrl: String, title: String) {
    self.userChoice = userChoice
    totalRated = totalRated + 1
    lblRated.text = "\(totalRated) rated"
    if totalRated > 0 {
        ratedView.backgroundColor = .ratedGoldColour
    }else{
        ratedView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    if totalRated >= 5 {
        btnFloatNext.alpha = 1
    }
    if totalRated > 5 {
        userChoiceMovieImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: rateImageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder"))
        lblUserChoice.text = "Great taste. We love the \(title) too."
    }
    var rating = 1
    if userChoice == "Hate it"{
        rating = 1
    }else if userChoice == "Good" {
        rating = 3
    }else{
        rating = 5
    }
    
    let guestRatingValues = GuestUserRate(id: rateMovieID, imageUrl: rateImageUrl, userRate: rating)
    GuestRateMovieView.createUserRating(guestRatingValues) =>", rateImageUrl)
    print("Received on movie", totalRated)
}
func getMovieDetails(){
    activityLoader.displayActivityLoader(image: activityLoader, view: activityLoaderView)
    let urlString = "https://t2fmmm2hfg.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/mobile/media/onboarding-items"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postParameters: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        "category": "tv"
    ]
    if let postData = (try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)){
        request.httpBody = postData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                print("got data")
                let jsonResult = try JSONDecoder().decode([Responder].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.movieObj = jsonResult
                    self?.moviesCollectionView.reloadData()
                    self?.activityLoader.removeActivityLoader(image: self!.activityLoader, view: self!.activityLoaderView)
                }
```

//                    jsonResult.forEach { course in print(course.type) }
}catch {
print(error)
}
}

```
        task.resume()
    }
    
    
}
var movieObj: [Responder] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getMovieDetails()
}
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return movieObj.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reUseMoviesCellID, for: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionCell
    
    cell.movieImage.image = nil
    cell.configure(with: movieObj[indexPath.row].packShot?.thumbnail ?? ""
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let modalVC = RateSingleMovieView()
    modalVC.movieID = movieObj[indexPath.row].id
    modalVC.movieTitle = movieObj[indexPath.row].title
    modalVC.movieImageURL = movieObj[indexPath.row].packShot?.thumbnail ?? ""
    modalVC.delegate = self
    modalVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    modalVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    present(modalVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
class MoviesCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

private var movieImages = NSCache<NSString, NSData>()
weak var textLabel: UILabel!
let movieImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return image
}()

let btnRate: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    image.clipsToBounds = true
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    image.alpha = 0
    return image
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    contentView.addSubview(movieImage)
    movieImage.addSubview(btnRate)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        movieImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        movieImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
        movieImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        movieImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
        
        btnRate.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.centerXAnchor),
        btnRate.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.centerYAnchor),
        btnRate.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        btnRate.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
    ])
    
    btnRate.tintColor = .white
    btnRate.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    btnRate.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0)
    btnRate.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    btnRate.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    btnRate.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    movieImage.image = nil
    btnRate.image = nil
}

func configure(with urlString: String, ratingObj: MovieRating){

    movieImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder"))
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Now in my modal where the user will rate. In my case I'm using swipe gesture for the rating

```
class RateSingleMovieView: UIViewController, ModalDelegate, ModalSearchDelegate {
func changeValue(userChoice: String, rateMovieID: String, rateImageUrl: String, title: String) {
        self.userChoice = userChoice
        totalRated = totalRated + 1
        
    }
var delegate: ModalDelegate?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    redBottomView.addGestureRecognizer(createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for: .up))redBottomView.addGestureRecognizer(createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for: .left))redBottomView.addGestureRecognizer(createSwipeGestureRecognizer(for: .right))
}
@objc private func didSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.direction {
        case .up:
        showUserRatingSelection(userChoice: "Good")
        case .left:
        showUserRatingSelection(userChoice: "Hate it")
        case .right:
        showUserRatingSelection(userChoice: "Love it")
        default:
            break
        }
}
@objc private func removeModal(){
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func showUserRatingSelection(userChoice: String){
    self.hateItView.alpha = 1
    if userChoice == "Hate it"{
        userChoiceEmoji.image = UIImage(named: "HateIt")
        lblRate.text = "Hate it"
    }else if userChoice == "Good" {
        userChoiceEmoji.image = UIImage(named: "goodRate")
        lblRate.text = "Good"
    }else{
        userChoiceEmoji.image = UIImage(named: "LoveIt")
        lblRate.text = "Love it"
    }
    userChoiceEmoji.alpha = 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        print("hello ", userChoice)
        self.delegate?.changeValue(userChoice: userChoice, rateMovieID: self.movieID!, rateImageUrl: self.movieImageURL!, title: self.movieTitle!)
        
        self.removeModal()
    }
    
}
}
```

I am able to use the delegate here to send info back to GuestRateMovieView Controller and update a label there. Now my only problem is displaying the icon on the selected cell with the user choice.

Comment: Please share the code for cellForItemAt .

Comment: your code is adding new layout constraints _on every layout cycle_

Comment: @VikasSaini have added my cellForItemAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note... setup your constraints in `init` -- ***Absolutely NOT*** in `layoutSubviews()`.

**Edit** -- forget everything else previously here, because it had nothing to do with what you're actually trying to accomplish.

---

**New Answer**

To clarify your goal:

- display a collection view of objects - in this case, movies
- when the user selects a cell, show a "Rate This Movie" view
- when the user selects a Rating (hate, good, love), save that rating and update the cell with a "Rating Image"

So, the first thing you need is a data structure that includes a "rating" value. Let's use an `enum` for the rating itself:

```
enum MovieRating: Int {
    case none, hate, good, love
}
```

Then we might have a "Movie Object" like this:

```
struct MovieObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var urlString: String = ""
    var rating: MovieRating = .none
    // maybe some other properties
}
```

For our data, we'll have an `Array` of `MovieObject`. When we configure each cell (in `cellForItemAt`), we need to set the Movie Image ***and*** the Rating Image.

So, your cell class may have this:

```
func configure(with movieObj: MovieObject) {

    movieImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: movieObj.urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder"))

    switch movieObj.rating {
    case .hate:
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsdown") {
            btnRate.image = img
        }
    case .good:
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "face.smiling") {
            btnRate.image = img
        }
    case .love:
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsup") {
            btnRate.image = img
        }
    default:
        btnRate.image = nil
    }
}
```

and your `cellForItemAt` would look like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionCell

    c.configure(with: moviesArray[indexPath.row])
    
    return c
}
```

When the user selects a cell, we can `present` a "Rate This Movie" view controller - which will have buttons for Hate / Good / Love.

If the user taps one of those buttons, we can use a `closure` to update the data and reload that cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = RateTheMovieVC()
    vc.movieObj = moviesArray[indexPath.item]
    
    vc.callback = { [weak self] rating in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        // update the data
        self.moviesArray[indexPath.item].rating = rating

        // reload the cell
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        
        // dismiss the RateTheMovie view controller
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    // present the RateTheMovie view controller
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Here's a complete example... I don't have your data (movie names, images, etc), so we'll use an array of "Movie Titles" from A to Z, and the cells will look like this:

[image]

and so on.

**enum and struct**

```
enum MovieRating: Int {
    case none, hate, good, love
}

struct MovieObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var urlString: String = ""
    var rating: MovieRating = .none
}
```

**collection view cell**

```
class MoviesCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let movieImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        image.backgroundColor = .blue
        return image
    }()
    
    let btnRate: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return image
    }()
    
    // we don't have Movie Images for this example, so
    //  we'll use some labels for the Movie Title
    var labels: [UILabel] = []
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(movieImage)
        
        for _ in 0..<4 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.textColor = .cyan
            if let f = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT", size: 60) {
                v.font = f
            }
            contentView.addSubview(v)
            labels.append(v)
        }
        
        // stack views for the labels
        let stTop = UIStackView()
        stTop.axis = .horizontal
        stTop.distribution = .fillEqually
        stTop.addArrangedSubview(labels[0])
        stTop.addArrangedSubview(labels[1])

        let stBot = UIStackView()
        stBot.axis = .horizontal
        stBot.distribution = .fillEqually
        stBot.addArrangedSubview(labels[2])
        stBot.addArrangedSubview(labels[3])

        let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .vertical
        st.distribution = .fillEqually
        st.addArrangedSubview(stTop)
        st.addArrangedSubview(stBot)
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(st)
        
        contentView.addSubview(btnRate)
        
        // setup constriaints here
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            movieImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            movieImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            movieImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            movieImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),

            st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.topAnchor),
            st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.leadingAnchor),
            st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.trailingAnchor),
            st.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.bottomAnchor),

            btnRate.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.centerXAnchor),
            btnRate.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.centerYAnchor),
            btnRate.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            btnRate.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
        
        btnRate.tintColor = .white
        btnRate.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        btnRate.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0)
        btnRate.layer.shadowRadius = 2
        btnRate.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        btnRate.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        movieImage.image = nil
    }
    
    func configure(with movieObj: MovieObject) {

        // I don't have your cell images, or the "sd_setImage" function
        //  un-comment the next line to set your images
        // movieImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: movieObj.urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder"))

        labels.forEach { v in
            v.text = movieObj.title
        }

        switch movieObj.rating {
        case .hate:
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsdown") {
                btnRate.image = img
            }
        case .good:
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "face.smiling") {
                btnRate.image = img
            }
        case .love:
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "hand.thumbsup") {
                btnRate.image = img
            }
        default:
            btnRate.image = nil
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

**example view controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var moviesArray: [MovieObject] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 200.0)
        fl.scrollDirection = .vertical
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 8
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(MoviesCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "c")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // let's change the collection view cell size to fit
        //  two "columns"
        if let fl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            fl.itemSize = CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width - fl.minimumInteritemSpacing) * 0.5, height: 200.0)
        }
        
        simulateGettingData()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return moviesArray.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "c", for: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionCell

        c.configure(with: moviesArray[indexPath.row])
        
        return c
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = RateTheMovieVC()
        vc.movieObj = moviesArray[indexPath.item]
        
        vc.callback = { [weak self] rating in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            // update the data
            self.moviesArray[indexPath.item].rating = rating

            // reload the cell
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            
            // dismiss the RateTheMovie view controller
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
        // present the RateTheMovie view controller
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func simulateGettingData() {
        
        // let's just create an array of MovieObject
        //  where each Title will be a letter from A to Z
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".forEach { c in
            let m = MovieObject(title: String(c), urlString: "", rating: .none)
            moviesArray.append(m)
        }
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**example "Rate The Movie" view controller**

```
class RateTheMovieVC: UIViewController {
    
    // this will be used to tell the presenting controller
    //  that a rating button was selected
    var callback: ((MovieRating) -> ())?
    
    var movieObj: MovieObject!
    
    let movieImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        image.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return image
    }()
    
    // we don't have Movie Images for this example, so
    //  we'll use a label for the "Movie Title"
    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .yellow
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 240, weight: .bold)
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        // let's add 3 "rate" buttons near the bottom
        let btnHate = UIButton()
        let btnGood = UIButton()
        let btnLove = UIButton()
        
        let btns: [UIButton] = [btnHate, btnGood, btnLove]
        let names: [String] = ["hand.thumbsdown", "face.smiling", "hand.thumbsup"]
        for (b, s) in zip(btns, names) {
            b.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            b.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            b.layer.masksToBounds = true
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: s, withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 32)) {
                b.setImage(img, for: [])
            }
            b.tintColor = .white
            b.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0).isActive = true
        }
        
        let btnStack = UIStackView()
        btnStack.spacing = 20
        btnStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        btns.forEach { b in
            btnStack.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        
        view.addSubview(movieImage)
        view.addSubview(titleLabel)
        
        btnStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btnStack)
        
        // setup constriaints here
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            btnStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            btnStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            movieImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            movieImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            movieImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            movieImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnStack.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        // here we would set the movie image
        
        // set the title label text, since we don't have images right now
        titleLabel.text = movieObj.title
        
        btnHate.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hateTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnGood.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goodTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnLove.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loveTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
    
    @objc func hateTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?(.hate)
    }
    @objc func goodTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?(.good)
    }
    @objc func loveTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        callback?(.love)
    }
    
}
```

---

It will look like this on launch:

[image]

Then we select the first cell and we see this:

[image]

We select the "Thumbs Up" button, and we see this:

[image]

Then scroll down and select-and-rate a few other cells:

[image]

You mention in a comment a *"cache DB"* ... assuming that will be persistent data, it's up to you to store the user-selected Rating.

Comment: Hi @DonMag why have u commented out movieImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder")) I need it to display the movie images from the url.

Comment: @chevi99 - I put comments in the code... specifically: *"I don't have your cell images, so let's just cycle through some colors..."* This was to show you how to implement `override var isSelected: Bool`. Implement the rest of your data and images as you had been doing.

Comment: Super cool @DonMag your implementation worked. I left one journey out how can I display the icon/image based on user rating? I have updated my post with the protocol I'm using to pass user rating back to my collection view. I'm struggling on how to get the value and write an if statement that will show the images
` if userChoice == "Hate it" {
    btnImage.image = UIImage("named" : "HateIt")
}else {
    btnImage.image = UIImage("named": "goodRate")
}`

Comment: @chevi99 -- I don't see anything in your post that talks about *"passing a user rating"*

Comment: I just added it. Can u check again

Comment: @chevi99 - ok, that has almost nothing to do with *"I want to display another image/icon on the cell when a user clicks on it."* -- Do you have a data structure where you are saving the user-selected ratings?

Comment: I immediately store in the cache DB. Kindly check my ` func changeValue(userChoice: String, rateMovieID: String, rateImageUrl: String, title: String) { } `

Comment: @chevi99 - that doesn't tell us anything. You have nothing in your `cellForItemAt` code that refers to the "saved rating" to display it on the cell.

Comment: please pardon my ignorance. I'm kinda stuck and I would be grateful if u could direct me on how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed when another cell is selected the previous thumbs-up icon on the other cell vanishes.

Comment: @chevi99 - I deleted my answer and gave you a new one. For future reference, try to think things through and clearly post what you're trying to do. Your original question - and the code you posted - really had nothing to do with your actual goal.

Comment: Sorry but in this case my movieObject is a struct which I have formed from the api. The json response from the api doesn't have rating. Moreover adding ```var rating: MovieRating = .none``` I get this error Type 'Responder' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' NB: Responder here is my movieObject. Really battling with this. Please pardon my ignorance

Comment: Can I go ahead and edit my code so u look at it well now things are very clear and code to me looks clean?

Comment: @chevi99 - I assume you are planning on saving the user's selected Ratings? If so, where are you expecting to save that information?

Comment: I'm saving it in my cacheDB I'm using SQLite for this

Comment: @chevi99 - *"How do I structure and save data?"* Is an entirely different question.

Comment: I'm not concerned with structuring and saving the data I only told you I'm saving in my cacheDB because you asked where I'm expecting to save the information. My major problem is displaying an icon on the cell based on the user's rating type

Comment: @chevi99 - *"displaying an icon on the cell based on the user's rating type"* ... the example code in my edited answer does exactly that. *"my movieObject is a struct ... `adding var rating: MovieRating = .none` does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"*. **That** I can't answer for you... as I said, *"how do I modify my data (my movieObject struct) so I can add/track/save an associated rating"* is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

in your `MoviesCollectionCell` file put function like this

```
func loadImageAfterClickingCell() { 
    // TODO: check this cell is already clicked and already download the image like if yourImageView == nil or not nil so you can add guard like guard yourImageView.image == nil else { return } similar to this
    guard let preparedUrl = URL(string: urlString) else { return } 
    yourImageView.alpha = 1
    yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: preparedUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder"))
}
```

And after that in `didSelectItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reUseMoviesCellID, for: indexPath) as! MoviesCollectionCell
    cell.loadImageAfterClickingCell()
}
```

A simple method injection like this must save you as you want.

Comment: This is not working and also what I want to achieve is to just display an image/icon on the image which has already been loaded on the cell. Please check this link to have an overview of what I want to achieve. https://www.seasfarm.com/collections.mp4

Comment: in the video, there's an overlay in the cell, after selected movie has rated, i guess data has passed to back with this rating and overlay become visible with centered emoji used for ratio, `cell.btnRate.alpha = 1` line can be used for this button visibility but what about setting a emoji for rate imageview to put content to this imageview then make it visible, for example
`cell.btnRate.image = UIImage(named: "ratedImageForExample")`
then
`cell.btnRate.alpha = 1`

Comment: I have implemented cell.btnRate.alpha = 1 and also cell.btnRate.image = UIImage(named: "ratedImageForExample") but still not working u can check my latest edit if I've done it the right way